# Unable to have inline code in a comment when a backslash is before the tilda

Tags: bug, formatting

When I write a comment, I believe my only option to *format as code* is to use tildas. But if there is a backslash before the tilda, it seems to escape, and ruin my code formatting.

Example: `F:\`

I can see in the previewer, as I'm typing this, it seems to work fine. But in my comments, that backslash seemed to escape the tilda and really jacked up the code formatting. How can this be solved?

Comment: Now I'm trying `F:\`  (there is a backslash before the closing tilda, but you may not see it) to see if it screws up my code formatting... But if I leave out the backslash and just do `F:` it works as expected. How can I unescape the backslash-tilda so it doesn't try to escape the tilda?

Comment: Yep, it didn't format as expected. But if I leave out the backslash and just do `F:` it works as expected. How can I unescape the backslash-tilda so it doesn't try to escape the tilda?

Comment: ``f:\`` .......

Comment: @HerrimanCoder - In the future less reliance on commentary will avoid formatting problems of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I unescape the backslash-tilda?

Use double tildas:

```
``f:\``
```

This will display in a comment as:

```
f:\
```

See my comment under your question.